# Snackbar appears behind AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-snackbar, snackbar

I want to show a Snackbar and an AlertDialog at the same time, but I'm having issues. The snackbar appears behind the AlertDialog. I'm performing validation in the onClickListener of the positive button and want to display the error messages in a snackbar with a clickable button. I'm using android.support.design.widget.Snackbar for the snackbar

**Show Snackbar**

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Message Content", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.setAction("Button Text", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }
})
.show();
```

I've tried using the following views:

1. dialog.getWindow().getDecorView()
2. findViewById(android.R.id.content)
3. findViewById(R.id.root_view)

Nothing seems to work. And since the AlertDialog is covering the snackbar, you can't click the button. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't believe the Snackbar was intended to be used in combination with an AlertDialog. I'd recommend displaying your form as a new Activity or Fragment and using either a dialog or Snackbar for validation.